# IBM Notes field limitation, option to store data as rich text?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, richtext

In an application I am experiencing problems with field limitations.

At the moment I am using a multiline edit box control on an xpage to capture the information and I save it in the back-end on the Notes document as a text field e.g:

```
doc.replaceItemValue("emplInformation", employee.getInfo());
```

I was not aware that users paste "complete stories" in the field so it breaks my functionality (I am not handling the error so the document will never be stored).

Therefor I was thinking that instead, perhaps I could save the information to a rich text field instead and hereby avoid the field limitation.

Is this a smart thing to do? Or, should I try other options?.

I have to mention that the user is not going to enter formatted text (yet). So I do not have to take notice of that. Nor that they will paste in images or html.

I have never worked with rich text or mime in Java before so I am not experienced in read/write such data. Any code example how to store it to the back-end document is highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider validation to limit user input, like 4k or so. RT brings many other problems in future (isSummary flag for example).

Comment: You can turn off the summary flag for the field and go to a higher limit. I think if you do this you can get up to 64KB for a text field. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/over_whats_new_in_fp8.html

Comment: Hello Howard, thank you for the tip. I will take it into consideration. When I look at the sample texts that users enter and the field size they hardly exceed the 32Kb limit.

Comment: IBM says 64kb for a RTF, in my experience anything bigger than 32K makes it so you can't open the document.  (The only solution is to remove the field from the back end.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store data in a field, was could be greater as the field limit, you may consider using the OpenNTF Domino API.
You can store in a single field, if to big, the field is automatically converted to a RichText item.
Is used it in our HR Assistant application, for info about to bypass the limit see, http://elstarit.nl/2018/01/18/make-the-nsf-modern-again-with-openntf-domino-api/

Comment: Hello Frank. This could be an option for me. But for my UI: how do I read the field, not knowing what type of field it is? in my java objects I have defined the type for the field. When my field is there of type String and the back-end document the type is rich-text I should convert the RT to String, or only read the text part of the RT if such is possible?

Comment: With ODA I just read doc.getItemValueString("json"), and I don't have to care about what kind of field it is. There are a lot more goodies in ODA, for example don't have to work with NotesDateTimes and Vector anymore.